# Convert ABSOLUTE position to FIXED

Tags: css

I have a div with tooltips inside and I have to convert it's position from absolute to fixed.

When I simply change the attribute it just changes to weird random position.

How should I track it?

Comment: Some code to work with?

Comment: What do you mean it just changes to a "weird random position"? Can you get a bit more specific?

Comment: Please post some code snippet or use https://jsbin.com/

Comment: The difference is that `fixed` doesn't take into account any postioned parent elements, while `absolute` does. If any ancestor of your element has position set to asbolute or relative you can't simply change the value and expect it to behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Your absolutely positioned element is positioned based on the position of the last relatively positioned ancestor. Look at the snippet below. Fixed is just based on the window itself. If you want to find the coordinates of where you need to set fixed, you need to use JavaScript to get those coordinates.

```css
.relative {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:80px;
  margin-left:120px;
  background:#CCC;
  }

.absolute {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:40px;
  background:#888;
  color:white;
}

.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:20px;
  left:40px;
  background:#333;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <p>I'm positioned relatively. The absolute div will be positioned relatively to me.</p>
  <div class="absolute">
    <p>I'm offset from my relatively-positioned parent</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed">
    <p>I'm a child of the relative position, but I'm fixed so I'm offset from the window</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer to the question, this answer almost makes the question look valueable :P

Comment: OK, so what do I need to do to place the second div in exactly same place but with position fixed?

Comment: From the answer above: "If you want to find the coordinates of where you need to set fixed, you need to use JavaScript to get those coordinates."